# Compare two excel workbook with multiple sheets for difference and saving in seperate excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I want to compare excel sheets of 2 different excel files and save the difference in a separate excel file.
I found this amazing code for comparing Excel files with multiple tabs and saving it in newly generated excelDiff sheet , but i am getting error as

**rows, cols = np.where(comparison_values == False) ValueError:
not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)**

here , is the code ->

'''

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

df1 = pd.read_excel('test_1.xlsx', sheet_name=None)

df2 = pd.read_excel('test_2.xlsx', sheet_name=None)


with pd.ExcelWriter('./Excel_diff.xlsx') as writer:

  for sheet, df1 in df1.items():
    
      # check if sheet is in the other Excel file
    
      if sheet in df2:
        
        df2sheet = df2[sheet]
        
       comparison_values = df1.values == df2sheet.values

        print(comparison_values)

        rows, cols = np.where(comparison_values == False)
        for item in zip(rows, cols):
            df1.iloc[item[0], item[1]] = '{} → {}'.format(df1.iloc[item[0], item[1]], df2sheet.iloc[item[0], item[1]])

        df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet, index=False, header=True)
```

'''
If anyone has better solution ,please post it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry, it looks like someone started to modify the original code without actually understanding any of it. I would suggest to check with the original coder and to use the original code to get an understanding first.

Comment: i have updated the code , Now i am getting  rows, cols = np.where(comparison_values == False)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
""

Comment: What is the reason to not use the original code? Is it kind of homework assignment?  Sorry again, these changes confirm once more that there is rather limited understanding of the original code. What is expected as the outcome of the line with np.where () and what kind of data is supposed to be the input for it?

Comment: yes , it is an assignment ,and we are asked to fix this .I believe the error is coming because of dataframe df1,df2sheet has different layout .Is there any way from which we can fix this issue.

Comment: So, you get the code with the mistakes and you are supposed to correct it? Sorry to ask, why don’t you try to solve together with your classmates?  As I proposed above (as a hint), you may want to check how the function np.where () works and walk backwards line by line to solve it. Also check what you see with the print() and whether this is what you expect to see. Then you will hopefully find another 2 issues. If you suspect the 2 Excel files having different layout why not just open them with Excel  and have a look? Good luck!

Comment: here the error is showing up because np.where() returns justo one object but you are trying to assign to two variables. rows and cols.